# Gradle config file for L version and old versions of android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm trying to create an android app with the new Material Design theme and can't get it to work on previous versions of Android.

I cant find any resource with the correct configuration.

This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

buildToolsVersion '20'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appname"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    L {
        compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
        minSdkVersion 'L'
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
    }
    Old {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1'
}
```

}

The app crashes and cant find the material design theme configuration (i've created a theme in values-21 folder)

If somebody can please help me with this i will appreciate!

Comment: Make sure you upgrade this to use the new AppCompat and Android 5.0 SDK not the Android-L preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lpreview = hasProperty('lpreview')

apply plugin: 'android'


android {
    compileSdkVersion lpreview ? "android-L" : 19
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    productFlavors { lpreview ? lpreview{} : classic{} }

    defaultConfig lpreview ? {} : {
        // Non-L-preview configuration
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }



}
dependencies {
    //wearApp project(':Wearable')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

Comment: tried this and here is the new error:
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processClassicDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1`

Comment: Change to com.android.support:support-v4:20.+

Comment: tried again and the app doesn't `recognizes android:Theme.Material.Light in v21\styles.xml file`.

`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.`